# NodeJS, Express, MySQL - Can't set header after they are sent

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I try to develop an NodeJS application with Express.
Here is my code

```
app.post('/open', checkStatus, function(req, res) {
  if (req.error) {
    console.log(req.log);
    return res.json(req.error);
  }

  console.log(currentDate() + colors.gray('>> ') + colors.bold(colors.cyan(req.method)) + ' ' + colors.green('200') + ' ' + req.url);

  var data = req.body;

  status.door.isOpening = true;

  setUser(data, function() {
    setOpening(data, function() {
      openTheDoorPlease(data, function(response, log) {
        if (status.door.isOpening) {
          status.door.isOpening = false;
          console.log(log);
          return res.json(response);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

and here the error

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/yourmajesty/Sites/arduino-test/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/yourmajesty/Sites/arduino-test/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:164:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/yourmajesty/Sites/arduino-test/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:250:15)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/yourmajesty/Sites/arduino-test/server/server.js:179:22)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/yourmajesty/Sites/arduino-test/server/server.js:255:50)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/yourmajesty/Sites/arduino-test/server/server.js:276:42)
    at Query._callback (/Users/yourmajesty/Sites/arduino-test/server/server.js:321:46)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/yourmajesty/Sites/arduino-test/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:85:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/Users/yourmajesty/Sites/arduino-test/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:144:8)
```

Actually, when the URL '/open' is called with POST method, the first time, everything is ok. But the second time, I have this error. 
All the answers I found talk about the `return`.

The entire code is available here: https://gist.github.com/fcordillot/48428cfccc260635672b9e27d86b5d07

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `status.door.isOpening = true;` looks like you're setting global data on your server.  Is that really what you intend to do - change data that all requests from all users see and use?

Comment: Where is this line in your code `throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors`?  You're telling us that's where the originates, but you don't show us the code associated with that.  That's what we need to see.

Comment: Also, your request handler has code paths where no response of any kind is sent. That is also not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several issues with your code:

1. You appear to be modifying global state with `status.door.isOpening = true;` that affects all users.  It also looks like you may have race conditions with that global state.
2. There are paths through your request handler that do not return any response.  For example if `if (status.door.isOpening)` is false, then you never send any response.
3. In `openTheDoorPlease()`, you add an event handler every time it is called.  Thus each time you call it, another event handler is in place an you will get duplicate response handling and will call your callback multiple times and, thus will try to send the response multiple times.  This is likely the problem causing the "can't set header after they are sent" message.

In this function, there are problems:

```
/*----------  Actions on Arduino  ----------*/
function openTheDoorPlease(data, callback) {
  // 
  // Do stuff to open the door here 
  //
  //
  socket.emit('event', {
    type: 'open-door'
  });

  socket.on('event', function(data) {
    switch (data.type) {
      case 'door-opened':
        if (status.door.isOpening) {
          doorOpened(function(response, log) {
            if (callback !== undefined) callback.call(this, response, log);
          });
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

}
```

If you are going to add a socket event handler, then you MUST remove it when the event occurs so they don't pile up.  But, this design in general will not work reliably because it's subject to race conditions.  Socket.io is simply not a request/response protocol.  When you emit an event and then wait for a response event, you have no way of knowing which response belongs with which request.  If you have multiple users using your system, they can easily mix up which events go where.  This code will need to be redone probably a different way.

4. Another global variable issue

In this code:

```
/*----------  Socket  ----------*/
var socket;
io.on('connection', function(sock) {  
  socket = sock;

  status.socket.isReady = true;
});
```

You are attempting to stick a connecting client connection into a global variable.  That means that **your server will only ever work reliably with one user**.  It will simply not work properly with multiple users connected to your server.  You cannot code this way in any server environment.  Servers handle requests from many different users and they all share the same global environment.  What you probably need to do is to be able to tell (from a given http request) which `socket.io` connection belongs to that user so you can get that connection and send data to it.

5. Similarly, your `checkStatus()` function seems to be using global state all over the place.

---

Unless you were intending to design a client/server environment that was only ever designed to work with one client at a time, a lot of this design needs to be rethought and redone to avoid using shared global state.  If you must keep state on the server, then you probably want most of that state to be per-user state (probably using a session object or something like that).  Any global state must be explicitly intended to be shared by all users and must be accessed in a way that is safe from race conditions if multiple users are accessing the server at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, first don't need to use return. second check that your functions (setUser, setOpening, openTheDoorPlease, etc) are not sending any header or response.
Here is your code not using return.

```
app.post('/open', checkStatus, function(req, res) {
  if (req.error) {
    console.log(req.log);
    res.json(req.error);
  }

  console.log(currentDate() + colors.gray('>> ') + colors.bold(colors.cyan(req.method)) + ' ' + colors.green('200') + ' ' + req.url);

  var data = req.body;

  status.door.isOpening = true;

  setUser(data, function() {
    setOpening(data, function() {
      openTheDoorPlease(data, function(response, log) {
        if (status.door.isOpening) {
          status.door.isOpening = false;
          console.log(log);
          res.json(response);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
You can find the entire code here : https://gist.github.com/fcordillot/48428cfccc260635672b9e27d86b5d07

Comment: I don't have any enviroment here to test but comment from line 50 to 57 (your middleware which edit headers) and tell me if it works.

Comment: If these functions are not getting passed the `res` object, then they can't be sending a response or headers on their own.